# How to measure the amount of times 0 & 1 occurs

Tags: c#, boolean, logic, console-application

Here is the code that outputs 1 or 0 depending on the equality of the 2 arrays

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Here());  
            }
```

Here is where the magic happens.

```
static int Here()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            PlayerInput();
            int[] intarray = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
            string[] sarray = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };


                int i = rnd.Next(10); // creates a number between 1 and 10
                int x = rnd.Next(10);
                string iarray = intarray[x].ToString();
                if (iarray == sarray[i])
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }



        }
```

it outputs 0 when the two arrays don't equal and 1 vise versa. now I want to count the amount of times it outputs 0 & 1.

Questions:

1. How could I do that?
2. Should I transfer the output to an array for easier manipulation?

Comment: When will you break your while loop?

Comment: are you familiar with lamda expressions..? you can do this easily using the following `.GroupBy, .Where, and .Select` I can post an example using non-Duplicates and Duplicates in a List<T> if you need see a working example to go from

Comment: How is your `while` loop supposed to exit?  Never use `while(true)` unless you really, really know what you're doing.  This will loop infinitely.

Comment: Also, why do you convert both `ints` to `Strings` to compare them? Just compare them as `int` values

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, it seems like you could simply have two counter variables:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int totalOnes = 0;
    int totalZeroes = 0;

    while (true) // need to replace this with something that will actually exit!!
    {
        int ret = Here();
        if (ret == 1) totalOnes++; else totalZeroes++;
        Console.WriteLine(ret);  
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Total Ones: {0} Total Zeroes: {1}", totalOnes, totalZeroes);
}
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to L J for pointing out that your `while` loop will never exit since you have `while (true)`.  You need to address that.

Comment: Ohh, U was a first one.. okay. But keep in mind, that here ```if (ret == 1) totalOnes++; else totalZeroes++;``` totalZeroes does not zero counter, its "not one" counter, because Here in future can return 2 or 10.

Comment: Can it, though? As he gave it, the returns can only be `0` or `1`

Comment: @tym32167 -- I agree with Hank. The question clearly states it returns zero or one.  Your method is quirky; I would just use a `switch` if I wanted to account for other possible cases.

Comment: @rory.ap ofcource both code will work and I dont want to say that your code is bad, just according with experience, requirements is changing often and variables name should reflect with variables values. In you case totalZeroes means how many times result is not equal 1, and I just wanted to notice it.

Comment: Just an input: there is no way the control will move out of `while` loop

Comment: @LJ -- Wow, I didn't even notice that.

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var zeroCount = 0;
    var oneCount = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        var result = Here();
        if (result == 1) oneCount++;
        if (result == 0) zeroCount++;
        Console.WriteLine($"Actual result {result}, zero count {zeroCount}, One count {oneCount}");     
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tinwor result of ```int Here()``` can be anything, because it returns ```int```. Think about this function as black box.

Comment: @tym32167 Technically, the OP could edit his `Here()` method to return any `int`, yes. But, we were asked to provide an answer for his current code, not the possibility of what his code could be in the future. `Here()` does indeed return an `int` but the return is a finite choice of `ints` at it's current state. If the OP never needs that method to return anything but 0 or 1, then why account for anything else?

Comment: I dont want to say that this code is perfect, I just mention that variables names should fit varibles values. IN my case ```zeroCount``` means how much result was zero. In case of answer from rory.ap, it means how much result not equals 1

Comment: That would be correct if you take the if statement and look at it by itself with no other factors. But, given the current `Here()` method, his `totalZeros` does indeed mean how many results were `0`. It is situationally correct, but universally vague. I do get your point but you do have to consider the situation of the variables when forming an opinion on ambiguity of variable names.

Comment: Yep, assuming that ```Here``` method is correct and work perfectly and have certain implementation as OP shows, yes, my point is not make sense. But Im not sure that this is filnal implementation of ```Here``` method and not sure that 1/0 - is final requirements. Assuming tnat, I dont want to allow ```Here``` method changes affect to other logic with counters. I agree that this is not related to OP answer, it only about how your code ready to be changed. Only from that perspective, assuming that requiremenst is not final and implementation will change, my note have chance to live :)

Comment: ooh, nevermind, just ignore me, should less work and more rest... :)

Answer (score -1):

```
static int Here()
        {

            Random rnd = new Random();
            PlayerInput();
            int[] intarray = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
            string[] sarray = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };

                **var Count1 = 0;
                var Count0 = 0;**
                int i = rnd.Next(10); // creates a number between 1 and 10
                int x = rnd.Next(10);
                string iarray = intarray[x].ToString();
                if (iarray == sarray[i])
                {
                    **Count1++;**
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    **Count0++;**
                    return 0;
                }



        }
```

Count0 will contain the number of times 0 was outputted.

Count1 will contain the number of times 1 was outputted.

Comment: `Count1` and `Count0` are currently unaccessible variables outside of `Here()` because the method is private.